# How to add current timestamp in the database. What is the format?

Tags: yii2

I want to add the current system time into database while inserting new record into database as in "time_created" column. PHP's time() function don't have support in yii2. I want yii2 specific time function that will help me save current timestamp. Anyone knows????

Comment: Not sure about other db's but if you're using MySQL you can have a timestamp column update itself, http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/timestamp-initialization.html

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 10):

You can use *yii\db\Expression* to perform SQL function

```
<?php
use yii\db\Expression;

$model->time_created = new Expression('NOW()');
$model->save();
```

Answer (score 8):

Yii 2 has special behavior for this. Just attach it to the model.
Add this to your model to `behaviors()` method:

```
use yii\behaviors\TimestampBehavior;
use yii\db\Expression;

public function behaviors()
{
    return [
        // Other behaviors
        [
            'class' => TimestampBehavior::className(),
            'createdAtAttribute' => 'time_created',
            'updatedAtAttribute' => false,
            'value' => new Expression('NOW()'),
        ],
    ];   
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work with batchInsert for some reason. I'm still getting NULL as the value. But if I set the attribute explicitly like this $myModel->creation_time = new Expression('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()'); it works

Answer (score 8):

You can also use `Yii2`'s `formatter` like below:

```
Yii::$app->formatter->asTimestamp(date('Y-d-m h:i:s')); //1410488596
Yii::$app->formatter->asDatetime(date('Y-d-m h:i:s')); //Sep 12, 2014, 2:21:56 AM
```

Answer (score 5):

Maybe this is old but it may help some one else. Add the below code in your model. Make sure you change the `createdAttribute` to your attribute. You also have to include:

```
use yii\behaviors\TimestampBehavior;
use yii\db\Expression;

public function behaviors()
{
    return [
        [
            'class' => TimestampBehavior::className(),
            'createdAtAttribute' => 'entry_date',
            'updatedAtAttribute' => false,
            'value' => new Expression('NOW()'),
        ],
    ];
}
```

Comment: How it's different from my answer?

Comment: @arogachev Because this answer is more readable and looks complete than yours.

Answer (score 2):

You can Simply use PHP's `date()` function as - **`date('Y-m-d H:i:s');`**

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways of adding timestamp, I suggest using UNIX timestamp for sake of dealing with timezone. For example in Google SQL instances you cannot setup timezone, but offset, which means that you would need to update offset twice a year because of summer/winter time. For that as someone mentioned you can also use behaviours:

```
public function behaviors()
{
    return [
        [
           'class' => AttributeBehavior::className(),
           'attributes' => [
               ActiveRecord::EVENT_BEFORE_INSERT => 'entry_date',
           ],
           'value' => function ($event) {
               return time();
           },
        ],

    ];
}
```

or you can simply just add before insert, like `$model->entry_date=time();` but as you will do this on every `INSERT` then behaviors are better choice.

And of course if you want to read formatted date, you can use:

```
\Yii::$app->formatter->asDate($model->entry_date);
```

For asDate formatter, you can read here:
   http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-i18n-formatter.html#asDate()-detail