# How to save timestamp in mysql using php?

Tags: php, yii2

I have startTime column as timestamp datatype in DB,I pass the timestamp(20160105123067) to save record, it automatically saves value '0000-00-00 00:00:00' into that database table. Actually I have write API in yii2. I trouble with this please help me..

Thanks in advance

```
$appointmentModel->startTime = $_POST['startTime'];
$appointmentModel->startTime = Date("Y-m-d h:i:s", $appointmentModel->startTime);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add current timestamp in the database. What is the format?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27378264/how-to-add-current-timestamp-in-the-database-what-is-the-format)

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
$appointmentModel->startTime = Date("Y-m-d h:i:s", strtorime($appointmentModel->startTime));
```

Instead of :

```
$appointmentModel->startTime = Date("Y-m-d h:i:s", $appointmentModel->startTime);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use like this.

```
$date =  $_POST['startTime'];
$timestamp = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($date));
```

Hope this help you.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$appointmentModel->startTime = $_POST['startTime'];
$appointmentModel->startTime = Date("Y-m-d h:i:s",strtotime($appointmentModel->startTime));
```

Answer (score 0):

You will define it in your model if you don't want to define it in your api

You will define it in model like this :

```
use \yii\db\Expression;



['startTime', 'default', 'value' => new Expression('NOW()')],
```